# Equilateral Triangle Bisection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help find different equation of (smooth continuous) curves through the centroid of an equilateral triangle bisecting the triangle area $\Delta$ into two equal parts.

I could not proceed after starting at a vertex $$ \int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\frac12 r^2 d\theta = \Delta/2 $$

Comment: Do you only need an example or you need more?

Comment: Derivation of DE of at least one partitioning smooth curve.

Comment: OK one possibility is we can start with y = - kx^2 through center and adjust k.

Comment: Your choice is good even though it is not what you are searching for. I mean it is not the differential equation. I found many other special ways but not the differential equation. If you want I can post a picture with my general idea.

Comment: Please post it as DE can be always found from them.

Answer (score 0):

This is my general idea:

1. We use two bump functions of the kind 
   $$
   f(x) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
     be^{ - \frac{1}
   {{a^2  - x^2 }}} \,\,\,\,if\,\,\,\, - a \leqslant x \leqslant a \hfill \\
     0\,\,\,\,elsewhere \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right.
   $$ and $g(x)=-f(x)$.
2. We translate them on the left and on the right of the centroid and we call them $f_L(x)$ and $f_R(x)$.
3. We define a new function $F(x)$ as
   $$
   F\left( x \right) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
     0\,\,\,\,\,if\,\,\,\,x \in \left[ {x_A ,x_E } \right] \hfill \\
     f_L (x)\,\,\,if\,x \in \left( {x_E ,x_F } \right) \hfill \\
     0\,\,\,if\,\,\,\,x \in \left[ {x_F ,x_L } \right] \hfill \\
     f_R (x)\,\,\,if\,x \in \left( {x_L ,x_M } \right) \hfill \\
     0\,\,\,\,\,if\,\,\,\,x \in \left[ {x_M ,x_H } \right] \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right.
   $$
4. The parametric curve obtained from this function satisfy your request.

[image]
Of course you can add as many couples of bump functions as you want and you can play with parameters freely with parameters $a$ and $b$ as long as the graph of $f$ stay inside the triangle and there is an interval where the function $F$ is zero containing $G$.

Comment: funtion should be smooth continous.

Comment: They are! That's why I used the bump functions: a function as $f(x)$ is $C^{\infty}$. You can learn more about them at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function